# Storing multiple OS Installation Media on an SSD

Tags: windows-7, installer

I would like to condense my bootable CD and DVD collection onto a SSD.

I have managed to write two Windows OS Installers to the SSD and successfully installed Windows from the SSD to 3 Different machines, but I haven't enough experience to write the scripts necessary to be able to over write a bootable partition with new OS installer without conflict.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

The format and reinstall time is so much significantly faster that my work time has been cut in half. I dont want to have to buy a separate ssd for each flavor of Windows

Answer (score 0):

WinSetupFromUSB

http://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/System-Enhancements/WinSetupFromUSB.shtml

This does most of the hard work for you.

Comment: http://www.winsetupfromusb.com

Answer (score 0):

This is an awesome tool for Windows iso's and can easily be modified for Linux/other .isos since it's based on GRUB.

http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-usb-drive-that-will-install-vista-win7-and-server-2008

I've personally accomplished the task seen in the tutorial and created a similar drive. My needs required mirroring recovery drives for TB's worth of different models of computers that I would frequently encounter during work and has been expanded to include diagnostics on a PXE server.

There are 2-3 other tutorials on that site covering ground for slightly different versions of the same process. I recommend looking into them since one may offer slightly more specific details or coherent explanation of the process.

The RmPrepUSB tool is also incredibly handy for the working with bootable drives, isos, GRUB, etc...

I've used RmPrepUSB in conjunction with other programs to create custom GRUB bootloaders for bootable iso's. (AllinOne Win .isos, Ubuntu, Hiren's BootCD, etc...) If you want I can give you the source code for my current setup, it's at the point where it's literally drag/drop an iso to the drive, copy/paste 1-2 lines that point to the new .iso in order to add it's menu option to the GRUB and it's good to go.

Honorable mentions. [Xboot](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/xboot-multiboot-iso-usb-creator/), [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), [SARDU](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/sardu-multiboot-usb-creator-windows/)